# How i can map two classes to one field

Tags: java, hibernate

What we have?
We have two subclases from Dictionary and QueueProfile. I want map field profile like in code below. How i can map this?

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Dictionary implements Serializable {}

@Entity
public class Speciality extends Dictionary{}

@Entity
public class LdpType extends Dictionary{}

@Entity
public class QueueProfile{
    Dictionary profile;
}
```

Or it's not posible in this case.
I know that i can create two implementations of QueueProfile with diferent fields and discrimination, but its not so elegant

Comment: Are you sure your example is correct? Your description and the code don't really match up for me. Especially the "two subclasses from Dictionary -and QueueProfile-" confuses me, QueueProfile is not involved in any subclassing here.

Comment: profile can already contain Dictionary's subclasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on which way round you want to store it. When using `@MappedSuperclass`, it expects that you're going to share one superclass, but it's clear from *the entity itself* which table to get data from. For example:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Dictionary implements Serializable {}
@Entity
public class QueueProfileUsingSpeciality extends Dictionary {}
@Entity
public class QueueProfileUsingLdpType extends Dictionary {}
```

It sounds like you actually want something that could either be `Speciality` *or* `LdpType`, in the `QueueProfile` entity. In which case, Hibernate knows where to get data for `QueueProfile`, but to instantiate `profile` it needs to know which table/entity/subclass to use. This is handled by using a discriminator.

```
public class Dictionary implements Serializable {}
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Foo")
public class Speciality extends Dictionary{}
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ldp_type_profile")
public class LdpType extends Dictionary{}
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="which_profile")
public class QueueProfile {
    Dictionary profile;
}
```